# I want to set the default value to my Date property by myself

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
<DataMember(isRequired:=True)>
```

Public Property SDate As Date?

Public Property EDate As Date?

in wcf client they acquire the defult values as Now. but i want SDate to have vale Now.Date and EDate as Now.Date.AddMonths(1). How can it be possible. I tried Constructor and setting default values after and before removing '?'.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand, but try the below

```
SDate = Now
EDate = Now.AddMonths(1)
```